# how to highlight text(annotation) in pdf using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, annotations, highlight

I am beginner in Php. I have to highlight text in Pdf i.e annotation using php. Is it possible?.   I have waste couple of days. Please suggest me any solutions.

Comment: Which piece of you use?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd means?

Comment: _I have to highlight text in Pdf i.e annotation using php._ So what is the PHP code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZendPdf](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf). It allows you to create or manipulate PDF documents. Also it supports various annotations like highlight.

```
const SUBTYPE_HIGHLIGHT = 'Highlight';
const SUBTYPE_UNDERLINE = 'Underline';
const SUBTYPE_SQUIGGLY  = 'Squiggly';
const SUBTYPE_STRIKEOUT = 'StrikeOut';
```

Use `ZendPdf\Annotation`  . Invoke`create` with subtype `Highlight`

**Edit**

You can install it via composer. `composer require "zendframework/zendpdf": "2.0.*@dev"`